# "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 405 error occurred when doing class-based-view in django

Tags: python, django, class, view, http-status-code-404

I tried to make two processes of uploading excel file and saving it into database by using class-based-view, but it occurred an error.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import UploadFileForm, InputForm
from .models import Memo
import pandas as pd
from django.views import View

# Create your views here.

class upload_file_and_saving_to_database(View):
    
    def upload_file(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
               form.save() 
               return render(request,'report/success.html') 
            
            else:
                form = UploadFileForm()
                return render(request,'report/upload.html',{'form':form})

    
    def saving_to_database(request):
        df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\leeta\OneDrive\바탕 화면\TK project\myproject\media\upload\sample_file.xlsx')
        df_cp=df
            
        analysis_with_list=df_cp.query('출금액!=0')
        analysis_with_list=analysis_with_list.loc[:,['적요','출금액']]
        analysis_with_list=analysis_with_list.groupby(by=['적요']).sum()
        analysis_with_list.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
   
        ss=[]
        for i in range(0,len(analysis_with_list)):
            st = (analysis_with_list['적요'][i]) 
            ss.append(st)
        for i in range(0,len(analysis_with_list)):
            Memo.objects.create(memo=ss[i])
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from report.views import upload_file_and_saving_to_database

urlpatterns=[
    path("upload/",views.upload_file_and_saving_to_database.as_view(),name="upload"),
```

the error occurred.
Not Found: /
[30/Dec/2023 15:39:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2169
Method Not Allowed (GET): /report/upload/
Method Not Allowed: /report/upload/
[30/Dec/2023 15:39:15] "GET /report/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

How can I solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: I don't see that you defined any `get` method from the view handling `upload/`.